# interaction effects and control variables

Tags: interaction

Suppose I have a panel model $y = a + \beta_1X +\beta_2C$ with many months of data for many individuals. $C$ is a control variable. I want to check whether the effect is different in one particular month, so I run the model $y = a + \beta_1X +\beta_2C + \beta_3XD + \beta_4D$ where $D=1$ in that particular month and $D=0$ otherwise. Alternatively, I can run  $y = a + \beta_1X +\beta_2C + \beta_3XD +\beta_4D  + \beta_5CD $. Intuitively I think the latter expression makes more sense since because $XD$ is zero everywhere, it is basically uncorrelated with all $C$, so the controls don't do their job. At the same time, for the same reason, $XC$ and $CD$ would all be perfectly correlated with one another, suggesting I should not do this. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: The key you are missing in both specifications is the main effect of $D$

Comment: thanks @MaartenBuis I forgot to write it down. but the question remains